# Making input reactive in flexdashboard shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm trying to make an input reactive to another in a flexdashboard shiny app.

Here is the df example:

```
> dat = data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:10],g1 = c(rep(24,5),rep(35,5)),g2 = c(2401,2401,2402,2402,2403,3501,3501,3502,3503,3503),val = seq(from = 10, to = 100, by = 10))
> dat
   id g1   g2 val
1   A 24 2401  10
2   B 24 2401  20
3   C 24 2402  30
4   D 24 2402  40
5   E 24 2403  50
6   F 35 3501  60
7   G 35 3501  70
8   H 35 3502  80
9   I 35 3503  90
10  J 35 3503 100
```

Create simple reactive set:

```
dat_r <- reactive({
    out = dat %>% filter(g1 == input$g1, g2 == input$g2)
    return(out)
})
```

Creates inputs for app:

```
shinyWidgets::pickerInput('g1','Select g1',choices = unique(dat$g1),
                          options = list(`actions-box` = T), multiple = T, selected = 24)
shinyWidgets::pickerInput('g2','Select g2',choices = unique(dat$g2),
                          options = list(`actions-box` = T), multiple = T, selected = 2401)
```

Create outputs:

```
renderDataTable(dat_r())
```

Which gives:
[image]

My question is if I select 24 in g1, the only options I want in g2 start with 24, if I select 35, the only options I want start with 35, how would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Shiny you cannot manipulate UI elements in this way. If you want to be able to change the options of an input dynamically, one of the possible ways is the following:

In the UI instead of the desired widget include a UIOutput for example:

```r
ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
     UIOutput("picker1"),
     UIOutput("picker2")
)
```

Then in the server you can define functions of the type:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
     output$picker1 <- shiny::renderUI({
         shinyWidgets::pickerInput('g1', 'Select g1', choices = unique (dat$g1), options = list(`actions-box` = T), multiple = T, selected = 24)
    })

     output$picker2 <- shiny::renderUI({
         shinyWidgets::pickerInput('g2', 'Select g2', choices = unique (dat$g2),
                           options = list(`actions-box` = T), multiple = T, selected = 2401)
     })
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use this in shiny flexdashboard as the question asked stated? I am running into the same issue a year after this question was asked but I am not sure that the code you posted can be used in a shiny flexdashboard.